# Is it valid to put table element into list element in HTML5?

Tags: html

So that is the question, can i do thing like this:

```
<li><table></table></li>
```

I can't check on W3 as it's disabled at my workplace...

Comment: You can check in your desktop itself with writing HTML5....

Comment: "I can't check on W3 as it's disabled at my workplace..." Where are you working that a site like w3.org would be off limits?

Comment: yes, you can place table inside.

Comment: Huge company, they dont allow to serve our development code to third parties -.-  Hariharan: yes, i know i can do that, i'm asking if it's valid to do that...

Comment: Thanks, just put a 'Yes' as an answer and i'll approve it...

Comment: @wintercounter — So download the validator and install a local copy.

Comment: @Quentin: Once he gets off work :)

Comment: @BoltClock — It sounds like the problem is a policy the forbids uploading HTML source code to the validator, not one which forbids visiting the W3C site.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You don't necessarily need to check with W3 for information like this.  Mozilla Developer Network is a great resource full of information regarding standards and compatibility.  For instance, the page for [`<li>` elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/li) describes them as follows (emphasis mine):

> Content categories: None.
>   **Permitted content: Flow content**.

And there's even a [section describing flow content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Content_categories#Flow_content):

> Elements belonging to the flow content category typically contain text or embedded content. They are: `<a>`, `<abbr>`, `<address>`, `<article>`, `<aside>`, `<audio>`, `<b>`, `<bdo>`, `<blockquote>`, `<br>`, `<button>`, `<canvas>`, `<cite>`, `<code>`, `<command>`, `<datalist>`, `<del>`, `<details>`, `<dfn>`, `<div>`, `<dl>`, `<em>`, `<embed>`, `<fieldset>`, `<figure>`, `<footer>`, `<form>`, `<h1>`, `<h2>`, `<h3>`, `<h4>`, `<h5>`, `<h6>`, `<header>`, `<hgroup>`, `<hr>`, `<i>`, `<iframe>`, `<img>`, `<input>`, `<ins>`, `<kbd>`, `<keygen>`, `<label>`, `<map>`, `<mark>`, `<math>`, `<menu>`, `<meter>`, `<nav>`, `<noscript>`, `<object>`, `<ol>`, `<output>`, `<p>`, `<pre>`, `<progress>`, `<q>`, `<ruby>`, `<samp>`, `<script>`, `<section>`, `<select>`, `<small>`, `<span>`, `<strong>`, `<sub>`, `<sup>`, `<svg>`, **`<table>`**, `<textarea>`, `<time>`, `<ul>`, `<var>`, `<video>`, `<wbr>` and Text.

So, those pages tell us that a `<table>` is indeed valid within a `<li>`.  Of course, you can find this information in mirrors of the HTML spec too, I just find MDN a little quicker to navigate.

Answer (score 0):

That's valid. I'm wondering if you really need a table there or you can use divs and CSS. I prefer using tables when I actually have to represent a table/grid and using  divs for disposition.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can able to do it, but you will get list item symbol before the table starts.

Comment: I imagine that's the whole point of putting a table in a list item in the first place.

Comment: yes, that may be wintercounter intention. i agree with @BoltClock

Answer (score 0):

Both `li` and `table` are block elements, so there is no known restrictions. However, there is easy way to check if page valid if you doubt: [W3C validator](http://validator.w3.org/check)

For example, create such page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>A</title>
</head>
<body>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <table></table>
        </li>
    </ul>

    <span>
        <div></div>
    </span>
</body>
</html>
```

And try to validate it. You'll see error about block `div` inside inline `span`, but you don't see anything about `li > table`.

Comment: "Both `li` and `table` are block elements, so there is no known restrictions." It's not always as simple as that.

Comment: In real world is _always not_ that simple, however, validator usage is often a good idea.